# Google Pagespeed Insights missing something

Tags: magento, google-pagespeed

I have two different domains(both hosting Magento - M1) for client on which I am working on. I have installed the extension - https://github.com/mediarox/pagespeed

Issue with example1 domain

With the help of this extension - JS files are moved to the bottom, correctly, which is evident from the GTmetrix analysis - which says

```
defer parsing javascript - A100
Optimize the order of styles and scripts - A100
```

yet in Google pagespeed Insight - it lists number of JS and CSS files as render blocking for example.

```
https://www.example1.com/…default/theme625/js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js
https://www.example1.com/…/theme625/js/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js
https://www.example1.com/js/prototype/prototype.js
https://www.example1.com/js/lib/ccard.js
https://www.example1.com/js/prototype/validation.js
https://www.example1.com/js/scriptaculous/builder.js
https://www.example1.com/js/scriptaculous/effects.js
https://www.example1.com/js/scriptaculous/dragdrop.js
https://www.example1.com/js/scriptaculous/controls.js
https://www.example1.com/js/scriptaculous/slider.js
https://www.example1.com/js/varien/js.js
https://www.example1.com/js/varien/form.js
https://www.example1.com/js/mage/translate.js
https://www.example1.com/js/mage/cookies.js
https://www.example1.com/js/ecommerceteam/cloud-zoom.1.0.2.js
https://www.example1.com/…default/theme625/js/jquery.easing.1.3.js
https://www.example1.com/…me625/js/jquery.mobile.customized.min.js
https://www.example1.com/…rontend/default/theme625/js/bootstrap.js
https://www.example1.com/…theme625/js/jquery.carouFredSel-6.2.1.js
https://www.example1.com/…default/theme625/js/jquery.touchSwipe.js
https://www.example1.com/…fault/theme625/js/jquery.bxslider.min.js
https://www.example1.com/…ntend/default/theme625/js/tm-stick-up.js
https://www.example1.com/…frontend/default/theme625/js/carousel.js
https://www.example1.com/…n/frontend/default/theme625/js/camera.js
https://seal.geotrust.com/…ame=www.example1.com&size=M&lang=en
```

Then in Second domain - 
Google Pagespeed Insight
for the mobile it lists number of files as render blocking:
but the same are not listed in the Desktop version.

Whereas on GTmetrix I get the same Result as:

```
defer parsing javascript - A100
Optimize the order of styles and scripts - A100
```

What I may be missing, which raises the issue of render blocking like this on Google pagespeed Insight.